# Android PopupWindow showAtLocation() vs showAsDropDown() - first one is working for me and second is not

Tags: java, android, mobile

I used the following code to show a PopupWindow in android, I want to pin a popup to a Button,

```
    btnShowPopup = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnShowPopup);
    btnShowPopup.setOnClickListener(this);

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if(v == btnShowPopup){
        View popupViw = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.popup_demo, null);
        PopupWindow popup = new PopupWindow(this);
        popup.setContentView(popupViw);
        popup.showAsDropDown(btnShowPopup,10,10);
        //popup.showAtLocation(popupViw, Gravity.BOTTOM, 10, 10);

    }
}
```

In this case `popup.showAtLocation()` is working well, but `popup.showAsDropDown()` not displaying any popups for me.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably working, but showing the popup below the visible window, as it is attaching to the lower left corner of the btnShowPopup view.